# How can I convert from a firebase document to a custom class in Node JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In node.js I'm getting the error below.  Any ideas why?

> Conversion of type 'Promise' to type 'Member[]' may be a mistake
> because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
> intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.   Type
> 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Member[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

```
export async function getFamilyMembers(tenantId: string, familyCode: string): Promise<Member[]> {
  return db.collection(`tenants/${tenantId}/members`)
.where('familyCode', '==', familyCode)
.get()
.then(snaps => {
  snaps.docs.forEach(doc => {
    return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
  });
}) as Member[];
}
```

EDIT:
If I remove the types and change it to

```
export async function getFamilyMembers(tenantId: string, familyCode: string) {
  return db.collection(`tenants/${tenantId}/members`)
    .where('familyCode', '==', familyCode)
    .get()
    .then(snaps => {
      snaps.docs.forEach(doc => {
        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
      });
    });
}
```

I just have to deal with the problem later.
I get the error

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'void'.

```
const familyMembers: Member[] | void = await getFamilyMembers(tenantId, familyCode);

      if (familyMembers === null) {
        isVerified = false;
        verificationFailMessage = `Sorry we can't find this code.  Please check it is correct.`;
      } else if (familyMembers.length === 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add Promise in front of Member.

```
export async function getFamilyMembers(tenantId: string, familyCode: string): Promise<Member[]> {
  return db.collection(`tenants/${tenantId}/members`)
    .where('familyCode', '==', familyCode)
    .get()
    .then(snaps => {
      snaps.docs.forEach(doc => {
        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
      });
    }) as Promise<Member[]>;
}
```